# Best way to create a template method (for a singleton class) that receives a template class as argument

Tags: c++, templates, directx

i have a singleton class thats my main engine.

since im using D3D11, and it uses the same ID3D11Device method to create all buffers (no matter the type), im trying to create a template method to create the buffers.

also what i use as source for the buffer is a std::array

so what im trying so far is:

```
template <size_t Size, typename T>
void CreateBuffer(BufferType bufferType, const std::array <T, Size>& source, ID3D11Buffer** out) {
    (...)
    bd.BindFlags = bufferType;
    bd.ByteWidth = sizeof(T) * source.size();
    (...)
}
```

and then i use it like:

```
ID3D11Buffer* buffer = nullptr;
array <SimpleVertex, 10> data; //this is the source data, 10 simple vertices
D3DEngine::GetInstance().CreateBuffer <10> (D3DEngine::Vertex, data, &buffer);
```

this works, but looks so ugly. that "10" as argument template forces me "hardcode" the size (i cant even use `<data.size()>` because it requires a constant as template argument).

is there a better way to achieve what i want? or i should use a different approach?
thanks.

Comment: CreateBuffer(D3DEngine::Vertex, data, &buffer) should be fine. What is your compiler?

Comment: VS 2010, it does compile like that but crashes on the call to the .CreateBuffer()

Comment: Interesting. I write a simple test program in VS2010, it calls CreateBuffer(const std::array <T, Size>& source) and prints out sizeof(T), Size and source.size(). Everything is good.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler should be able to infer both size and type arguments.

Why is your engine a singleton? There's little point in that. And you could just return the pointer, instead of taking a pointer to it. And a raw instead of resource-managing pointer? Glad I don't maintain your code.

Comment: thanks for answer. the compiler infers both types, but if i dont tell what size it is, the program crashes when the .CreateBuffer() is called. i cant even cout the Size just to see if it was right, it just crashed on the call to the method. as for the return buffer instead of taking a pointer is because i use exceptions all over the place, maybe its not the best way to go (especially with a singleton) but im just trying to get things done and ill clean it up after.

Comment: @sap: That's a completely different problem.

Comment: @sap we hardly get to clean up after. We get to maintain. But not clean up. Better to do it the right way. Maybe work out with your boss to stay late and leave early next day.

Comment: @sap: Could be a compiler bug. You'd have to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

I made a quick [test-case](http://ideone.com/lxHS7) and it seems to work without manually specifying the size of the array.

This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>

template<size_t S, typename T> size_t CreateBuffer(std::string const & s, std::array<T, S> const & source)
{
    // do something
    return S;
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    std::array<std::string, 10> arr;
    size_t ret = CreateBuffer("my string", arr);
    std::cout<<"Size: "<<ret;
    return 0;
}
```